# What is the meaning and reading of 小奴?

Tags: meaning

I saw it used recently but don't remember the line. It was being used toward a group of subordinates, as 小奴ら. I can't find the word in any dictionary or being explained online. What is the meaning and reading of 小奴?

Comment: "Heard"? So are you sure these are the right kanji? Or do you mean you saw it somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I meant saw. I wrote this question when I was tired. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

こやつ is usually written in hiragana. But in kanji, it's **此奴**, not 子奴 nor 小奴. You can find this word [in jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%AD%A4%E5%A5%B4), [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/82436/meaning/m0u/), [Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%93%E3%82%84%E3%81%A4), and any other decent dictionary.

こやつ is a dated word used in place of こいつ. It often has a derogatory or accusatory nuance. Today, we mainly see こやつ in samurai dramas, historical novels and such. If you heard this used referring to someone's subordinates, probably it was for showing his humbleness to someone else (ie, introducing A's subordinates to A's boss).

By the way, according to [this page](http://cjjc.weblio.jp/content/%E5%B0%8F%E5%A5%B4), 小奴（こやっこ）seems to refer to "infant" or a certain type of servant in the Edo period. It's a very rare word, and I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: Umm, subordinate means someone lower than you, doesn't it?

Comment: @kuchitsu I was thinking of introducing A's subordinates to A's boss. (eg. "将軍様、こやつらが私の手下でございます")

Comment: some people still use it on the internet (like 2-chan) when they are talking bad about other people.  example:  http://minkara.carview.co.jp/smart/userid/889619/blog/36436970/

Comment: I asked some friends and they also read it as "ko-yatsu-ra".  Maybe using 小 is just to make it more rude.

Comment: i guess it depends if you read it in a story about Edo period, or if you read nowadays on the internet. People in 2-chan, for example, always create new words and sometimes they become the "correct" meaning on a colloquial context.

Comment: @DiogoSouza Do you mean that 小奴 in that page is not a typo but a word recently (intentionally) coined by Japanese net users? I doubt it. Do you have similar recent examples? If I'm not mistaken, it's Chinese people who like to prefix 小 to make words derogatory ([this page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC) explains *why* 小 is derogatory...)

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but I've seen it in some others pages too... and @ElSigh could have seen that word in one of these pages too, so - being the correct word or not - I think it is important to know the "typo" version too. Anyways, I guess your answer was more educational and correct, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is こやつら (koyatsura), which I would translate as something like "These f****** bastards".

奴 is a derogatory way to say "he/she". Something like "This man".

Putting the 小 before 奴 makes it worse, and shows more anger and disrespect for the subject.

ら is just to make it plural.

Comment: If there is a ら after 小奴 , I would personally read as "こいつら" which is much more used than "こやつら".  I'm not sure if it's the correct reading though.